# Установка английского языка для виджетов, сгенерированных Qt

Tags: c++, qt5

возникла необходимость устанавливать язык текста стандартных виджетов(QMessageBox, QPrintDialog, и т.п.).

Насколько я понял, при запуске приложения, Qt смотрит язык системы, после чего пытается подгрузить файл перевода `qt_XX.qm` из папки "стандартных переводов" фреймворка, расположенных по пути, указанном в `QLibraryInfo::TransationPath`. Основная проблема в том, что английский язык вшит в код и не имеет отдельного qm-файла.

Хотелось бы узнать: существует ли более красивое решение, чем создание собственного англоязычного qm-файла в папке "стандартных переводов" и его ручного подключение в проекте?

Comment: Существует. В документации есть информация об этом. Копайте в сторону `QCoreApplication::installTranslator()`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Копал в доках для версий 5.5.1 и 5.12 и ничего похожего не нашёл: для удаления подгруженного фреймворком транстятора нужен указатель на него, а у меня его нет. Установка 'QLocale::setDefault' на какую-либо англоязычную страну так же не влияет на подгружаемый язык.